# how to throw a type error in variadic function like the one in printf throws

Tags: c, gcc, error-handling, compilation

If I am compiling with `gcc`, and I have the `Wall` and `Werror` flags enabled, I will be able to catch some errors like the following when using the printf function and interrupt the compilation.

```
main.c:40:5: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Werror=format=]
     printf("Len:[%d]\n", "str");
```

In here, I am using `%d` format specifier, but passing a `char *` and `gcc` detects that during compile time. So my question is how could I go about implementing such error throwing in my program. To elaborate what I mean, Say I was making my own custom printf function using variadic functions and the write function(from the `unistd` library), how would I let the gcc compiler throw an error when ever the format specifier and the item in the va_list doesn't have the same data type.

so my custom printf would have the following prototype.
`int _printf(const char *format, ...);`

so I want the gcc compiler to throw an error when ever some one wants to use my printf function as `_printf("Len:[%d]\n", "str");` like it would with the normal printf function.

I dont know where to start or what to actually look for? do I read more about GCC or is this something I could do with just c.

Comment: look for `__attribute__((format(printf, FMT_INDEX, FIRST_ARG)))`. It's documented.

Comment: If you are using GCC or Clang, consider [the `format` and `format_arg` attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes).

Comment: ok guys thanks I will check out the things you have said